# Resetting value in the setter/getter in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a scenario. I need an alternative to what I am thinking for it

I am having attendance management system wherein an employee is supposed to log in his/her start time and end time. 
I calculate the duration (because its needed as well) = end time - start time.

Now, the scenario is if the employee forgets to enter the start time and directly enters the end time while leaving the company, I assume that he was on time. hence, the duration would be (assumed start time - end time).

Flow of the app.

Main Activity = displays the information of the employee
First Activity = Employee is supposed to enter the start time/end time

(Main Activity > First Activity).

Now, if we consider the scenario then the employee is on the first Activity to input the end time (start time not yet logged, hence will be assumed.     I have a setter for the same say, setStartTime).

If the back button is pressed from the first activity, then what happens is the end time is not logged but the start time starts getting reflected.

I want to remove the setter of the start time. I can have a reset method for the same. But I don't want to go by this way because if its a normal scenario then also it will attempt to remove the start time.

Secondly, I don't wanna go with the flag in onBackPressed.

Is there any other alternative to this?

Comment: I don't think this is an Android related question, but.. any code so we can understand better what you're saying?

Comment: Why don't you use an default value from eg. settings for start/end time and use this if the "user values" are null/empty?!